# Upgrading PHP to 5.5.9

Tags: php, nginx, centos, upgrade, fpm

There is an open-source project I want to install on my server, [Grav](https://getgrav.org), but it requires PHP 5.5.9. I currently have PHP 5.4.16 installed on a CentOS 7 server running on NGINX. Actually, it is PHP-FPM. So my question is what is the easiest and cleanest way to achieve this?

I have read many articles online regarding this and each one seems to have a different approach such as uninstalling the current version of PHP and reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: Side note: if you can, you should upgrade to PHP 7.1 rather than 5.5 which is already unsupported, and PHP 5.6 and 7.0 have a limited shelf life left too.

Comment: @RobbieAverill I am just concerned that upgrading from 5.4.16 to 7.1 will cause parts of my code to stop working. Is this a valid concern?

Comment: Of course, upgrading anything has this concern :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a more modern version of PHP you need to use an alternative repo.  There are a few out there to choose from, that have traditionally packaged up a newer version of LAMP stack components, like Remi, but for the Centos7 vagrant I'm currently using, I went with [webtatic](https://webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/).

You should simply follow the instructions for setting up the alternative repo with yum.  Currently that involves:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

Once installed do a `yum search php` and you'll find php versions 5.5, 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1 to choose from.

Instead of yum install php you're going to do something like `yum install php56w`.

For example on my VM, this is what I have for php:

```
[vagrant@localhost:~]$ rpm -qa | grep php
php56w-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-process-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-opcache-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-xml-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w7.noarch
php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-cli-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-mbstring-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-pdo-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-mysqlnd-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-fpm-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-gd-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64
```

You will need to uninstall your current php version, so this is an involved operation, and you want to have done a dry run, and be confident that you know what you're doing.

As for confidence that something won't break, with Vagrant/Virtualbox/Docker etc., there is no excuse for not testing this out in a VM first.

Not to mention that these are foundation tech for state of the art development these days.

Here's a quick and simple Vagrantfile for a vanilla Centos7 box you can have up and running (assuming you get Vagrant installed and working).

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.20.20"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "./data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```